# resolve a relative path to another relative path in Python

Tags: python, path

I have a relative path which is relative to another relative path, and I want to join them:

```py
rel_path1 = '../../data/a'
rel_path2 = '../../main.xml'

# pseudo function: join_rel_paths
result = join_rel_paths(rel_path1, rel_path2)

# My expectation
expected_result = '../../../main.xml'

assert result == expected_result
```

Is there any lib which could achieve this?

- I tried `pathlib.Path`: `(Path(rel_path1) / Path(rel_path2)).resolve()` -> it returns an absolute path with `cwd`
- I tried `urllib.parse.urljoin`: `urljoin(rel_path1, rel_path2)` -> `main.xml` not what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected result of your example should be `../../main.xml`, i.e. the same as `rel_path2`.  The two `..` in `rel_path2` strip off the last two components from `rel_path1`, leaving it as `../..`.  Then `main.xml` follows.  (But look further down to see how to strip off the last component of `rel_path1`.)

You can achieve this by using `os.path.join` followed by `os.path.normpath`:

```
rel_path1 = '../../data/a'
rel_path2 = '../../main.xml'

tmp = os.path.join(rel_path1, rel_path2)
result = os.path.normpath(tmp)
```

This gives `'../../data/a/../../main.xml'` for `tmp` and `'../../main.xml'` for `result`.

If you want to treat the last component of `rel_path1` as a file (and ignore it), you can use `os.path.dirname` to do so:

```
rel_path1b = os.path.dirname(rel_path1)
```

This sets `rel_path1b` to `'../../data'`, which you can then use in place of `rel_path1` to obtain `'../../../main.xml'`.